# Haskell. Fastest way to find similar elements in two Data.Map

Tags: haskell

I am trying to compare elements from two maps with a comparator function. Resulting solution should return a list of key value pairs from the first map that are similar to some values from the second one (only values are being compared).
The input looks like following:

```
let a = fromList [(0,15),(1,150),(2,39),(3,18)]
let b = fromList [(0,151),(1,39),(2,0),(3,1)]

-- Function that performs comparison. Returns True if items are similar
isSimilar :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isSimilar a b = abs (b - a) <= 1
```

The result should be following:

```
result = [(1,150),(2,39)]
```

I ended up with following implementation:

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as M
import Test.Hspec

type Elem = M.IntMap Int


-- Function that does all the work
getSimilarities :: Elem -> Elem -> [(Int,Int)]
getSimilarities cur intersected = M.foldrWithKey (\k p lst -> if M.null (check p)
                                               then lst
                                               else (k, p) : lst) [] cur
    where check pnt = M.filter (isSimilar pnt) intersected

-- Comparator that helps to filter out unnecessary values
isSimilar :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isSimilar a b = abs (b - a) <= 1 

-- Main function that runs the test
main :: IO ()
main = hspec spec

spec :: Spec
spec = do
        it "Get similarities test" $ do
            let xs        = [3,31,0,151,25,120]
            let mp        = M.fromList $ zip [0..(length xs)] xs

            let xs'        = [5,17,32,150,9,90]
            let mp'        = M.fromList $ zip [0..(length xs')] xs'

            let expected   = [(1, 31),(3, 151)]
            getSimilarities mp mp' `shouldBe` expected
```

However, I do not really like "check" function as I do not need to form a new map there, I just need to check value.
Could you please suggest if there is a more efficient and performant way of doing what I need? Thanks.

Comment: I can' think of any way to compare values more efficiently using that data structure. On keys, we have log-time lookup (see e.g. `lookupGE` which could be used to search for similar keys), but on values we don't have anything. Perhaps you should construct the set of the values of the second map (cost: N*log N) and then use that set to perform many lookups (N lookups, log N each). This might be better than the N^2 approach you seem to follow right now.

Comment: I am relatevely new to Haskell, so I decided to use maps as a container because in other languages it is quite fast. Maybe you could recommend me what is better in case I need to store some kind of a key-value pair? Also, with sets I do not see a lookup function that accepts predicate as parameter. Could you please clarify what exactly I should use?

Comment: The naive solution is to compute the cross product of your two lists and filter that using your `isSimilar` function. That takes O(n^2) time. If you use *ordered* containers, and can assume that  candidate pairs have the form `(x+/-d, x+/-d)` for some constant `d` (in your case here, `d == 1`), you can build the candidate list in only O(n lg n) time. (Which on a second reading is what @chi is suggesting, I think.)

Comment: Haskell is no exception here -- its maps are roughly similar to those in other languages. Given a key, you can quickly lookup the value. But, if you only have the value, you need to scan all the map. There is no lookup function with a generic predicate since that has to be slow. The only fast lookup is key->value. You can search for "what is the next key, starting from X?" using `lookupGE` and friends, quickly.

Comment: AFAICS, you don't really use the second map as a map, you only care about its values. So, start taking all the values and put them in a `IntSet` (to be done only once). Then use `IntSet.lookupGE` to perform your `check`. I can't guarantee this will be faster, but it could be, especially for large maps/sets.

Comment: You've got your keys and values switched!

Comment: Also, a fun edge case you might want to ponder: `isSimilar (-9223372036854775388) 420` evaluates to `True` on 64-bit machines (and `isSimilar (-2147483228) 420` on 32-bit machines). My answer assumes this is simply a bug and would not mark those as similar; if that's actually intended behavior things get much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with any `isSimilar` function, you can't do asymptotically better than your proposal. But for specific `isSimilar` functions, it is often possible to do better. In the specific case of

```
isSimilar a b = abs (b - a) <= 1
```

you can build a set of all values near your second collection's values and do set intersection, like this:

```
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as S

getSimilarities :: Set (Arg Int Int) -> [Int] -> Set (Arg Int Int)
getSimilarities cur intersected = S.intersection cur . S.fromList $
    [ Arg (i+di) (error "The impossible happened: ignored Arg values were inspected in getSimilarities")
    | i <- intersected
    , di <- [-1, 0, 1]
    ]
```

See it go in ghci:

```
> xs = [3,31,0,151,25,120]
> mp = S.fromList $ zipWith Arg xs [0..]
> xs' = [5,17,32,150,9,90]
> getSimilarities mp xs'
fromList [Arg 31 1,Arg 151 3]
```

I leave deciding whether you actually want to use maps and tuples instead of sets and `Arg`s, and functions for converting between them, to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I changed an implementation a bit to have a tuple (Int,Int) as a value and isSimilar definition to isSimilar (a1,b1) (a2,b2) = let f = abs (a2-a1) f2 = abs (b2 - b1) in f <= 1 && f2 <= 1. But it should also be working.